# MVC Login Failure using ReturnURL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My goal is to return a 401 error from my login controller. I fired up a stock MVC site with the built in .Net Membership Provider. What is currently happening is, when I return a 401 from my controller, I am getting a `http://xxxxx/Account/Login?ReturnURL=XXXX` I dont want the redirect to happen, i just want the controller to return a 401 so I can handle it on the client side. Any help with this issue would be appreciated.

All of the Code is stock membership provider except for the LOGIN Method on the Account Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
    // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
        //     return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(401);
    }
}
```

Comment: You expected `ActionResult` return type and values return is an instance of this type. If you want to return pure status code take a look of `IHttpActionResult` from web API templates

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didn't follow mIchaelMao advice. I had to comment out `LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")` on line 28 in the Startup.Auth.cs

Answer (score 0):

In MVC5, there is a `Startup.cs` in the project, the code is

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(WebMVC.Startup))]
namespace WebMVC
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

comment out the `ConfigureAuth(app);` and it will not register the function in the `Startup.Auth.cs` so you can get the HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized

Comment: if i do that I will not run all of the authentication that MVC put in for me.